# OnClientClick not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am having some problem with OnClientClick.

I added a button into my webform like this.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
        style="top: 307px; left: 187px; position: absolute; height: 26px; width: 90px" 
        Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return validate()" />
```

And i am writing a javascript inside `<head>`immediately after the `<title>`.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        if (document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1%>").value == "") {
        alert("textbox1 should not be empty");
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("<%=TextBox2 %>").value==""){
        alert("textbox2 should not be empty");
        }
                        }
</script>
```

`TextBox1`and`TextBox2` are the Id's of two textboxes.

But when i click on Submit button, OnClick is firing but OnClientClick is not firing.

Whats the problem ?

Please help.

Comment: first thing your javascript code have error so it's not behaving as you are expecting it to do.

Comment: Try adding OnClientClick="javascript:return validate();" and also make sure that you have no errors in your script by looking into errors table in error console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When taking the ID from the textboxes, you'll have to use `<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>` in your javascript.

And you should also `return false` from the validate-function when an error occurs.

Replace your javascript with:

```
function validate() {
    if(document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value == '') {
        alert('Textbox1 should not be empty');
        return false;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').value == '') {
        alert('Textbox2 should not be empty');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can solve this even easier if you use jQuery, then you can use `$('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').val()` instead of `document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:-

```
document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").value

document.getElementById("<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>").value
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing i see, is that you are using `"<%=TextBox1%>"` without the `.ClientID`,
which is what recognizes the texbox on the client side. naturally, without id, you javascript  cannot find the object (and probably throws an exception as well)

Answer (score 1):

`(document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1%>").value == "")`

will render as

`(document.getElementById("System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox").value == "")`.

so try to use `document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").value` in the javascript function.